# Find all id's that are listed in JSON object with jQuery

Tags: jquery

From an ajax request i get this response

```
val1,val2,val3
```

and have a list with id equivalent to them like

```
<select multiple>
  <option id="val1">val1</option>
  <option id="val4">val4</option>      
  <option id="val5">val5</option>
  <option id="val2">val2</option>
  <option id="val6">val6</option>
  <option id="val1">val3</option>
</select>
```

how can i give all option ids that are in the ajax response the attr selected?
like this:

```
<select multiple>
  <option id="val1" selected="selected">val1</option>
  <option id="val4">val4</option>      
  <option id="val5">val5</option>
  <option id="val2" selected="selected">val2</option>
  <option id="val6">val6</option>
  <option id="val1" selected="selected">val3</option>
</select>
```

I hope this is clear!
many thanks in advance

Comment: you cant do that! there can only be one `selected` `option` in a dropdown. and uve got SO many elements with `id` as `val1`. Thats also not right. You can have only one unique element with a unique id.

Comment: You should no use `id` attribute for `option` tag. @hungerpain, how about multiselect lists?

Comment: i dont see a `multiple=multiple` attribute @YD1m .. thats why i said its not possible

Comment: Summary: 1) use `multiple` attribute for `select` tag, 2) do not use same id for more than one element, 3) do not use id attribute for `option`

Comment: you are both right the i just forgot the multiple. And the multiple val1 was just some typo and totally not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things :

- **Change all the `id` attributes in your `option` to `value`.** Its not proper to use `id` in options. [And besides, you seem to be using the same `id` for multiple elements, which is semantically wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types). If `val` is not used, the text inside option will be taken as value of the option.

  ```
  <select>
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val4">val4</option>      
    <option value="val5">val5</option>
    <!-- rest of your options -->
  </select>
  ```
- Then, **you'll have to use `multiple` select if you need to choose more than one selected option.** Your `select` must look like this:

  ```
  <select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val4">val4</option>      
    <option value="val5">val5</option>
    <!-- rest of your options -->
  </select>
  ```

Now, for your problem, you could just `split` the data you get from the `ajax` call into an array and then pass it to jQuery's `val`. This will save the JS engine a lot of time to search for ids and change the attribute of the options.

```
//store your ajax response in a variable
var values = 'val1,val2,val3'.split(',');
//assign multiple values to <select>
$("select").val(values);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/J7exP/4/

For more info on `val`, [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 4):

Try using [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), you also need to set the multiple attribute of select to allow [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) selection.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J7exP/1/)**

```
var arr = 'val1,val2,val3'.split(',');
$('select option').filter(function(){
    return arr.indexOf(this.id) != -1;
}).prop('selected', true);
```

**Mulitple attribute of Select**.

> This Boolean attribute indicates that multiple options can be selected
>   in the list. If it is not specified, then only one option can be
>   selected at a time, [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

**jQuery filter()**

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .filter() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the
>   matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each
>   element; all elements matching the selector will be included in the
>   result.